# Reload localStorage from disk

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite, firefox, local-storage

I'm asking this in relation to Firefox, but solutions for other browsers are welcome too!

If I want to reload a page, I press <kbd>F5</kbd>.

If I want to drop the cache and reload all page assets from the server I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>.

Neither of these methods causes the browser to reload the localStorage content from the disk (`~/.mozilla/firefox/foobar.profile/webappsstore.sqlite`).

My test case for this feature is below:

1. I open a web page (`http://localhost:8080`), or already have it open.
2. I open the console and run:

   ```
   window.localStorage.setItem("foo", "bar");
   ```
3. Some job runs (perhaps triggered by cron, perhaps manually). This job opens the localstorage DB file (`~/.mozilla/firefox/foobar.profile/webappsstore.sqlite`), and commits some changes to a key in the localhost scope (`UPDATE webappsstore2 SET value='baz' WHERE key='foo' AND scope='tsohlacol.:http:5000'`).
4. I reload the page and run:

   ```
   window.localStorage.getItem("foo");
   ```

   - I *expect* to see `"baz"` returned.
   - I *actually* see `"bar"` returned.
5. I close Firefox, the re-open it and load `http://localhost:5000`.
6. I open the console and run:

   ```
   window.localStorage.getItem("foo");
   ```

   - I see `"baz"` returned.

**My question:** Why does a hard reload not cause localStorage to be reloaded?
Is there another way to do this? Is it a bug?